# Automatically jump to a certain part of a WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm making a Chrome App, and i'm using the web view tag, which is similar to an iframe.

Is there a way to load halfway down the webpage that's inside the web view?

I have tried:

```
<webview onLoad="window.scroll(0, 150)" class="test" src="http://example.co.uk/test.aspx"></webview>
```

But it seems that would be far to easy. I'm not convinced its even possible.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a hint for you: assuming that code would execute on webview load (it wouldn't, but that's a separate issue), what would `window` refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for a moment that code would execute (it won't because of the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#what)), `window` would refer to the app's page, not the embedded page.

You need to execute the code in the context of the embedded page.

If you worked with Chrome extensions before, you would know that the part interacting with web content is called a [**Content Script**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Apps have a similar concept for [`<webview>` elements](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview). You can either declare in advance which pages should get which content script while they load, or you can explicitly load a content script.

So, suppose you have a file `content.js` with the following contents (excuse the pun):

```
window.scroll(0, 150);
```

Also, assume you have a script `app.js` running inside your app page, and a variable `webview` is a reference to the `<webview>` in there.

Then, you can make the webview execute it:

- Declaratively, by calling [`webview.addContentScripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-addContentScripts) **before** loading the page (e.g. before setting `src` from `app.js` code):

  ```
  // Assuming <webview id="wv"></webview>
  var webview = document.getElementById("wv");
  webview.addContentScripts([{
    name: "ExampleRule",
    matches: ["http://example.co.uk/*"], // can be as narrow as you wish
    js: ["content.js"]
  }]);
  webview.src = "http://example.co.uk/test.aspx";
  ```
- Explicitly, when the page is already loaded:

  ```
  // Assuming <webview id="wv" src="http://example.co.uk/test.aspx"></webview>
  var webview = document.getElementById("wv");
  webview.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
  ```

It is, of course, possible to make `content.js` much more sophisticated (for example, receive commands from the app) and/or more precisely control the timing of your operation - but those are at this point generic content script questions for which you can find solutions elsewhere or ask a new question.

Comment: Why do i need 2 js files?

Comment: One file per context? You have 2 nested documents, your app page and the embedded page. A script is only "in" one document, and reusing a single script for both situations is a bad idea in general.

Comment: No i know i thought you were saying i should make a content.js and an app.js. Shall i just stick all of that JavaScript in my current JS file?

Comment: Here's an analogy. Suppose you have an algorithm to shop in a shop, and to get a haircut. Should you glue them together and try to execute all steps regardless of whether you step into a shop or a hair salon? It's better to keep them (logically) separate. And in an app there's even a third script, the background one, for _yet another_ context. Again, separate. So, yes, I'm saying you need (at least) 3 separate files unless you want complex switching logic "let's see if I'm in a shop or not".

Comment: Note: you can use `executeScript`'s `code` parameter instead of a separate file for such a trivial one-liner. But in general it's cleaner if you have a separate file, and you have to use a separate file for `addContentScripts`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125104/discussion-between-xan-and-rhys-edwards).