# Automatically jump to a certain part of a web view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-app

I'm making a Chrome App and I'm using the web view tag which is similar to an iframe.

Is there a way to load halfway down the webpage that's inside the web view?

I have tried:

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Assuming <webview id="wv"></webview>
var webview = document.getElementsById("wv");
webview.addContentScripts([{
name: "ExampleRule",
matches: ["http://sentifeed.marstons.co.uk/Index.aspx"], // can be as narrow as you wish
js: ["content.js"]
}]);
webview.src = "http://sentifeed.marstons.co.uk/Index.aspx";

var webview = document.getElementsById("wv");
webview.executeScript({
file: "content.js"
});

$(".box1").click(function () {
$(".header").css("position", "fixed");
$(".bookAtable").fadeIn(1000);
$(".content").hide();
$(".headerPara").slideUp();
$(".back").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".marstonsLogo").css({
    "opacity": "0.0",
    "height": "48px"
});
});

$(".box5").click(function () {
$(".sentifeed").fadeIn(1000);
$(".content").hide();
$(".headerPara").slideUp();
$(".back").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".marstonsLogo").css({
    "opacity": "0.0",
    "height": "48px"
});
$(".header").css("position", "fixed");

});
$(".box3").click(function () {
$(".inmoment").fadeIn(1000);
$(".content").hide();
$(".headerPara").slideUp();
$(".back").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".marstonsLogo").css({
    "opacity": "0.0",
    "height": "48px"
});
$(".header").css("position", "fixed");

});

$(".back").click(function () {
$("webview").hide();
$(".content").fadeIn(1000);
$(".headerPara").slideDown();
$(".back").css("visibility", "hidden");
$(".marstonsLogo").css({
    "opacity": "1.0",
    "height": "75px"
});
$(".header").css("position", "relative");

});

$(".login").click(function () {
$(".boxWrapper").show();
$(".login-page").slideUp(600);

});

});

window.onload = function () {
document.querySelector(".exit").onclick = function () { //close windows button
    window.close();
};
}
```

My content.js:

```
window.scroll(0, 150);
```

html:

```
<webview id="wv" class="sentifeed"></webview>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894014/automatically-jump-to-a-certain-part-of-a-webview/ Note: the two methods I list are pretty much mutually exclusive. Don't use them together.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**JQuery Code**

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#wv').offset().top //wv id of webview
}, 1000); //Time to scroll
```

Comment: Does not apply: the goal is not to scroll the _embedding_ page that contains `#wv`, but the page _embedded_ inside `#wv` (which acts similarly to an iframe)